# Angle brackets from XML replaced with HTML codes?

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I am trying to read the content of an XML file (`configs.xml`) and insert it somewhere in the middle of another XML file (`workspace.xml`).

This is the code:

```
require "nokogiri" 

workspace = File.open("workspace.xml")
xml = Nokogiri::XML(workspace)
workspace.close

# Add new configs
configs = File.read("configs.xml")
xml.search('component[name="RunManager"]').each do |node|
    node.content=configs
end

puts xml
```

The output looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
  <component name="AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindow">
    <option name="state">
      <GlobalState/>
    </option>
  </component>
  <component name="RunManager" selected="Android Application.Run on device">    
    &lt;configuration default="true" type="AndroidTestRunConfigurationType" factoryName="Android Tests"&gt;
      &lt;module name="" /&gt;
      &lt;option name="TESTING_TYPE" value="0" /&gt;
      &lt;option name="INSTRUMENTATION_RUNNER_CLASS" value="" /&gt;
      &lt;option name="METHOD_NAME" value="" /&gt;
      &lt;option name="CLASS_NAME" value="" /&gt;         
    &lt;/configuration&gt;
</component>
  <component name="ShelveChangesManager" show_recycled="false"/>
  <component name="SliceManager" selected="Android Application.Run on device">
    <option name="analysisUIOptions">
      <AnalysisUIOptions/>
    </option>
  </component>
</project>
```

As you can see, the inserted content in the middle has all angular braces `< >` replaced with HTML codes `&lt; &gt`, and I don't know why, though I suspect this has to do something with encodings.

What is most interesting is that if printing the content of `configs.xml` alone (the one that gets inserted and modified) then the output is as expected:

```
<configuration default="true" type="AndroidTestRunConfigurationType" factoryName="Android Tests">
      <option name="TESTING_TYPE" value="0" />
      <option name="INSTRUMENTATION_RUNNER_CLASS" value="" />
      <option name="METHOD_NAME" value="" />
      // ............
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set the contents of a node you actually set its *text* contents, meaning, Nokogiri automatically escapes it.

To add a node to your XML you need to use [`add_child`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-add_child)

```
configs = File.read("configs.xml")
xml.search('component[name="RunManager"]').each do |node|
    node.add_child configs
end
```